# semantic analysis opensource tool - suggestions needed

Tags: sentiment-analysis, semantic-analysis

I've a book review site, where readers can write reviews about books, other users can post comments. I wanted to know following things automatically whenever new review publish or new comment published.

(1) whether book review is positive or not? How much % positive / negative?

(2) whether comment made by particular user is positive or not? How much % positive / negative?

(3) I want to read Tweets about particular book and wanted to check whether the tweet is positive or not?

bottom line, I want some tool suggestions (opensource), which I can use for my website. Website is written in PHP and I'm looking for some semantic analysis tool which I can customize to meet my need or which best fit my need.

if not, I want to know if its easy to build one with minimal requirements. I know PHP, Perl, Shell Script. I can learn Python. I know C++, Java may be right language to start from scratch; but don't have much experience.

Comment: that's probably worth a few billion dollars.

Comment: This would be very-very difficult task to solve (as irreputable mentioned, though, do not underestimate a billion dollars) and still producing not reliable output. So, the usual way is to propose some voting options you sure have seen in lots of places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open source semantic analyses engine incubated in the Apache Software Foundation, currently, called [Stanbol](http://stanbol.apache.org/). It provides APIs to interface with it over HTTP as well as through a Java API if needed. It's pretty advanced, but generally speaking if your needs are simpler you can always try some SaS solution like [uClassify](http://www.uclassify.com/browse/uclassify/Sentiment).

Answer (score 1):

In response to your first request, I'd suggest you create a form where the user has a voting option (such as a x/5 star rating, etc) then you would calculate the average from all of the reviews.